# Django query for transactions only where there are multiple transactions for company on the same date

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm

I have a model that consists of company name and transaction date columns.  How do I construct a Django query that retrieves only those records for which there are multiple records for that company on the same date?  It should exclude any records if there is only one record for that company on that date.  Heres what my data model looks like:

```
class Sales(models.Model);
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    transactionTimeStamp = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: `transactionDate` is `CharField`, which is not recommended

Comment: It stores a scraped string.  Is sufficient for my purposes.